# Вызов Dockerfile из Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

Как корректно выполнить build для Dockerfile, если он лежит непосредственно в корне репа? При этом отмечу, что Jenkins крутится внутри docker-контейнера. Я так понимаю, в контейнере Jenkins необходимо устанавливать также docker? Или же нужно просто настроить коннект между докером на хосте и jenkins-ом в контейнере.

Примечание. Если Dockerfile лежит в отдельной папке (когда несколько пайпов), то можно прописать через dir путь к папке с Dockerfile и вызывать уже docker build -t *название*.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker

Comment: Добрый день! А как можно сделать коннект между контейнером где крутится Jenkins и самим Docker daemon на хосте, где установлен docker ?

Comment: Обратитесь к документации https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/